# Replace a character in a String?

Tags: java, string

i have a problem with replacing a specific character in a string with another string. The problem is that i can figure out to remove  the old character and i get the character and the string next to each other. here is what i did until now.

```
public class zeichenErsetzen {
public static String ersetzeZeichen(String w,char b,String v){
    String ersetzt="" ;
    for(int i=0;i<w.length();i++){
        ersetzt += w.charAt(i);
        if(w.charAt(i)==b)
            ersetzt +=v ;
    }
    return ersetzt;
}
public static void main(String []args){
    String str = "Dies ist ein i";

    System.out.println(ersetzeZeichen(str, 'i', "ast"));
}
```

}

This is what i get i use this

> Diastes iastst eiastn iast

and this is how it is supposed to be

> Dastes astst eastn ast

Comment: Please post your code here, not as links.

Comment: you should only do *line 6* if it is **not** the char - so put it in ```else```

Comment: sorry i didn't know that im not allowed to post images

Comment: Thank you rala it worked

Comment: @Zitrone, you can post images when images are relevant. Code we prefer to have as text so we can copy-paste it and play around with it if needed (not that we do that often, only the option should be there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
ersetzt += w.charAt(i);
if(w.charAt(i)==b)
    ersetzt +=v;
```

You're adding each letter, regardless if it is the one you want to replace.
Add an additional `else` to fix this.

```
if(w.charAt(i)==b) {
    ersetzt +=v;
}
else {
    ersetzt += w.charAt(i);
}
```

Now a letter is added only if it **doesn't** match the one you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  StringBuilder class

```
    final String hello = "Hello";
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hello);
    sb.setCharAt(0, 'x');

    System.out.println("New String after replace: " + sb.toString());
```

Comment: I can't use a StringBuilder, i can only use length() and charAt() methodes.

Comment: If you wanted a fancy or just real-world solution, you would probably use a regular expression.